# Is there a way to abort a download from onDeterminingFilename

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to abort/prevent files save dialog during or after

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function (item, suggest) {

        suggest({
            filename:item.filename,
            conflict_action: 'prompt',
            conflictAction: 'prompt'
        });
        // conflict_action was renamed to conflictAction in
        // https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/f1d784d6938b8fe8e0d257e41b26341992c2552c
        // which was first picked up in branch 1580.
    });
```

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-cancel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `chrome.downloads.cancel`:

```js
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function (item, suggest) {
    suggest({
        filename:item.filename,
        conflict_action: 'prompt',
        conflictAction: 'prompt'
    });

    if(true) { // your cancel condition
        chrome.downloads.cancel(item.id);
    }
});
```

And yeah, you still need to call `suggest` because only items which are in progress may be canceled.

Comment: OK thanks that exposed that my other methods being asynchronous is causing my problems.

Comment: Excellent! Was struggling with `cancel` as I kept getting "Unchecked runtime.lasterror: Download must be in progress".  It was, as you say, because without the `suggest` the download isn't in progress! Thanks